# (Safely) Disable dGPU on 2018 15" MacBook Pro?

Tags: gpu

Is there a way to safely disable the Radeon Pro 560X dGPU on the 2018 15" MacBook Pro?

I know I can go the other way (force dGPU only) via the 'Automatic graphics switching' check box in Energy Saver but that is the opposite of what I want to do :)

I know on older models it was possible via magic nvram options.

Is it even possible on the 2018 MacBook Pro?

Edit: I should mention I have tried gfxCardStatus (and a more up-to-date port) however this does not **block** the dGPU from becoming active it simply switches back to the iGPU if something does fire up the dGPU. I want to **fully disable** the dGPU so it cannot be activated.

Comment: You can try using [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io); however it will not switch to the integrated GPU if an external display is attached or a program that requires the discrete GPU is running, e.g. Keynote. _Note that I'm not affiliated with the developer of the aforementioned app._

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I should have mentioned I have tried using gfxCardStatus as well as the port by Steve Schow at https://github.com/steveschow/gfxCardStatus but neither the original nor port _block_ the dGPU from becoming active.

Something simple such as going to Google Maps in Chrome will switch to the dGPU then gfxCardStatus will flip it back to the iGPU. 

This isn't what I want. I want to **fully disable** the dGPU from ever become the active GPU even for a second.

Comment: What happens when you boot in safe mode.  Is this acceptable for you?

Comment: Safe mode is not an option. I need a fully functional, normal environment.

Comment: I am unsure if the nvram variable changes are valid on the 2018 models which is the reason for my post. Rather than just link to an answer for a 2014 model MacBook Pro (with Nvidia dGPU) I would appreciate a link to something verifying it works on the 2018 models as well. Sorry but I can't guinea pig with this machine. I have searched a lot but cannot find anyone who has tried the nvram changes on a 2018 model.